# Wrong local date format saving to SQL Server with Laravel

Tags: sql-server, laravel, date, laravel-5

Our code in Laravel receives a date in Y-M-D format and tries to save it to a SQL Server database.

The code receives these dates via APIs for many tables and we cannot change this functionality everywhere.

SQL Server language is italian and our code is OK with a Y-D-M date.

Is there a way to specify the date format once for all or the locale used in the database connection configuration?
Setting the language via statement doesn't work.

Our code is something like this:

```
DB::statement('SET LANGUAGE us_english');
DB::table('tablename')->insert($saveData);
```

Comment: Personally, if you can, I would change the value of `$saveData` to be in the format `yyyyMMdd` before you try to insert it.

Comment: I would like to add to what @Larnu said.

You can use something called [carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/). This is the most used datetime api used with laravel and will be very easy to implement. ***tip*, look at formatting :)**

Comment: Thanks, but we receive the date via APIs in YMD format.
Since we have this situation in many tables, it would be better to change the database connection and not change $savedata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem writing on SQL Server.
It depends strictly on the language set in the database: https://database.guide/how-to-set-the-current-language-in-sql-server-tsql/

If the problem persists, you must check the user with which the database interacts and check the configuration, if it is different from the Administrator user, execute this command:

```
ALTER LOGIN your_login WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = us_english
```

And then:

```
Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert date format to Italian using LARAVEL Carbon Date library.

Like below :

```
$date = carbon::now()->locale($yourLocale);
```

Here is the Carbon library locale example : https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization